# C mutually referencing static initializers

Tags: c, gcc, static, initialization

Is it possible in C to have mutually referencing static variable initializers, as shown in the example below?

The example compiles, without warning in gcc -Wall, if line 2 is added to pre-declare "B".  Line 2 is distasteful because it also defines B, as does line 4.  The splint lint program, with -weak checking, warns that "B" is defined twice: "*Variable B redefined.  A function or variable is redefined. One of the declarations should use extern."*

Typically a declaration would be made with the extern keyword, but extern and static cannot be used together, and will not compile under gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>                               /*1*/
volatile static void * B;                        /*2*/
volatile static void * A = &B;                   /*3*/
volatile static void * B = &A;                   /*4*/
int main()                                       /*5*/
{                                                /*6*/
    printf("A = %x, B = %x\n", (int)A, (int)B);  /*7*/
    return 0;                                    /*8*/
}                                                /*9*/
```

Thank you

Comment: I wonder why you would need this?

Comment: This is a simplified example.  In my embedded application this technique initializes a linked list of menus shown on an 20x4 LCD display.   Each menu has pointers to adjoining menus for navigation.

Comment: As a non-question-answering aside, might it be simpler to store the menus in an array and link by index instead of pointer?

Comment: Sounds like splint doesn't understand tentative definitions.  I suggest you file a bug report with the developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notwithstanding the strange placement of `volatile` with relation to `static`, the code you posted is perfectly valid C. It uses a C-specific feature called *tentative definitions*. This feature makes sure that you have only one `B` in your program: both definitions of `B` define the same entity. There's nothing "distasteful" about it.

The warning you get from splint is invalid. In C++ language this would indeed constitute a multiple-definition error, but not in C. The comment about `extern` makes no sense whatsoever within the context of C language.

Comment: K&R2 (A10.2) defines tentative definitions for external objects only, not static.  However the newer ISO specs support this answer by specifically allowing tentative definitions for static variables.

Comment: @a b: I'm sure that is not the case. You misinterpreted the meaning of the term "external" in this context. "External" does not stand for external linkage. The term "external" in the title of "6.7.2 External object definitions" of the original ANSI C89/90 (and, I'm sure, in K&R2) refers to definitions made *outside of functions*, in *file scope*. "External" in this case simply means *non-local*. 6.7.2 in C89/90 explicitly allows tentative definitions for objects declared with `static`. Despite being published in 1988, K&R2 is in sync with C89/90, so it should state the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This is pointless.

EDIT:

Yes, there's no need in 'extern' (Thanks, AndreyT and Adam Rosenfield), but `&B` has a type of `void**`, not `void*`.

Of course, `void**` casts to `void*`, but what's the point? If you want aliases or pointers to each other, then just declare a third variable, "the buffer", and point to it in A and B.

```
unsigned char SomeBuffer[LENGTH];

void* A = SomeBuffer;
void* B = SomeBuffer;
```

Comment: `extern` would give it external linkage instead of internal linkage.  It's not a redeclaration, it's actually what's called a *tentative definition*, and it's perfectly cromulent C.

Comment: `extern` might help to achieve what exactly? The code is perfectly valid as is.

Comment: @AndreyT: I don't know what the OP is really trying to achieve, so I suggest pointing to some actual container. The "extern" keyword does not help, I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may look like you are defining a cyclical loop, but in fact you are not.  The C `&` operator is the *address-of* operator and gets the address of the variable in question.

As @AndreyT pointed out, line 2 has the effect of *tentatively defining* `B` so that line 3 knows about it.  You could **think of** line 2 as allocating the memory location for `B` and then in line 4 you put a value there.

The code is functionally the same as if you had written it like the following:

```
volatile static void * A;
volatile static void * B;
int main()
{
    A = &B;
    B = &A;
    printf("A = %x, B = %x\n", (int)A, (int)B);
    return 0;
}
```

So, in line 3 you define `A` to point to the address of `B`.  In line 4 you define `B` to point to the address of `A`.

Lets say that `A` and `B` have the following memory addresses:

```
&A == 0xAAAAAAAA
&B == 0xBBBBBBBB
```

The code in line 3 does the following:

```
A = 0xBBBBBBBB;
```

Then in line 4 it does the following:

```
B = 0xAAAAAAAA;
```

Now if you were to dereference `A` and `B` you would get the following (caveat, you'd have to cast to a dereferenceable pointer type first):

```
*A --> 0xAAAAAAAA
*B --> 0xBBBBBBBB
```

That is completely valid, but might not be what you are intending to do with your code.

Keep in mind there are two distinct values at play. First is the value of the pointer.  Second is the address of the pointer.

The only reason you would need to use `extern` would be to use a variable defined in another object file (ie in `file1.c` you want to use a global variable defined in `file2.c`).  The `static` keyword when applied to a global variable means the variable is *file-static* or that it can only be used within that file.  So the two are obviously at odds with each other.